# Removing quote marks and spaces within a URL

Tags: regex, r, url

I am an R beginner so please keep things as simple as possible.

I am trying to build a URL for fetching Yahoo Quote data. After unsuccessfully trying the "R in Nutshell" script, I turned to assembling my own. This is an example of the URL that I generated:

```
"http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv? s=XLK &a= 2 &b= 24 &c= 2014 &e= 04 &d= 07 &f= 2014"
```

I am unsure how to eliminate the quotation marks and spaces within this output. I did manage to get rid of the quote marks with `factor()`, but then could not get rid of the factors. `Gsub` does not like the quote marks with or or without the `\`. Furthermore, tries with regex for the spaces did not like `[ ]`s.

I'm open to alternates to my approach, but please keep them at a very basic level.

Comment: If you created that url using the `paste` function, you might want to consider looking at using `paste0` instead, which removes spaces when joining strings together. And all character strings like the url you have will be printed with `""` around them. The string itself does not actually contain `""`'s.

Comment: Why don't you ask about what you got wrong in the script from "R in a Nutshell" before you try doing it a different way?  You could also show us the R code that you are using to get the result that you currently have.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. I will study them all tomorrow.

R is daunting at this point, but, typically, I'm hungry for knowledge. So every side trip adds to the general sense of the coding. 

Adding the demands on my rusty, minimal RE skills added to my confusion.

Comment: RE. the O'R script. 
Searching the first bug led  http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596801700
Look for page 183.

This line froze me.
 ,formatC(as.integer(format(from,"%m"))-1,width=2,flag="0"),sep="")) 

I looked the formatC command, but I did not understand the rationale for it or the command (given zero background in C). 

I remain curious about formatC in general and in this specific script. Please feel free to clue me in. 

Thanks again to all. 

Michael, from the high mountains of central Colorado USA.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `paste()` to create URLs. Instead use a function, like
`httr::modify_url` specfically designed to create them:

```
library(httr)
base_url <- "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv"

modify_url(base_url, query = list(
  s = "XLK", 
  a = 2,    # start month
  b = 24,   # start day
  c = 2014, # start year
  d = 04,   # end month
  e = 07,   # end day
  f = 2014  # end year
))

## [1] "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=XLK&a=2&b=24&c=2014&d=4&e=7&f=2014"
```

This will also take care of correctly escaping characters that need it.
Even better, you could turn this into a function that documents itself
through use of named parameters:

```
library(lubridate)

yahoo_stock <- function(stock, start, end) {
  start <- ymd(start)
  end <- ymd(end)

  modify_url(base_url, 
    query = list(
      s = "XLK", 
      a = month(start), b = mday(start), c = year(start),
      d = month(end),   e = mday(end),   f = year(end)
    )
  )
}
yahoo_stock("XLK", "2014-02-24", "2014-07-04")

## [1] "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=XLK&a=2&b=24&c=2014&d=7&e=4&f=2014"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove the quotation marks with the following `regex`:

`'\"'` and replace with `''` with the `g` modifier activated to replace all matches.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/kV3kO0